# Kendo MVC Grid Action Argument

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo MVC grid with model

```
public  class CountryViewModel
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

    }
```

and action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Countries_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, CountryEntityModel Countrymodel)
{
  ....
}
```

if I change argument name in action to

> country

it does not post model, because my model has property with same name. Also for update and destroy actions. It can be save time for someone. And of course it will be good to have explanation.

Answer (score 0):

ASP NET MVC model binding is case sensitive.  If the model has a field `Country` and the parameter passed into the action is named `country` the automatic model binding will **not** place the `country` value in the `Country` field.